# Wildcard in a pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my `Makefile` I have a rule to compile Fortran source files, like so

```
.SUFFIXES:

%.o: %.[fF]
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This has worked fine on several machines.  When I tried it on another machine (incidentally with a *newer* (GNU) `make`, 3.82 instead of 3.81), it did not work, and I had to replace it with two separate rules for `.f` and `.F`.

The wildcard works without the `%`, i.e. this works:

```
.SUFFIXES:

test.o: test.[fF]
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that was working and wasn't just the built-in rules doing what you were expecting before?

Comment: Yes, the `.SUFFIXES:` disables them.

Comment: .SUFFIXES disables old-style suffix rules not pattern rules. There are default pattern rules for those pairs also and those would still be active even with `.SUFFIXES:` as you have set I believe.

Comment: Well, the fact of the matter is that, with an empty `Makefile` and a file `test.f` in the current directory, `make -n test.o` outputs `f77   -c -o test.o test.f`; but with a `Makefile` that contains exactly the line `.SUFFIXES:`, it says `make: *** No rule to make target `test.o'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can fully reproduce the behavior here. It is a [regression in make 3.82](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=31621). The discussion attached to the bug report suggests using [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) to work around the problem. I've tried it and got it to work in a simple test setup:

```
.SUFFIXES:

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: $$(wildcard %.[fF])
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Using the file above and two test files named `test.f` and `test2.F`, here's a couple commands I issue and the output produced by the Makefile:

```
$ make -n test2.o
f77 -c test2.F -o test2.o
$ make -n test.o
f77 -c test.f -o test.o
```

The workaround works both with 3.81 and 3.82.